# Trying to add new customer by getting Database Error Error Number: 1054

Tags: codeigniter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp1xy.png)This is my add function in controller

```
    public function add($type = 'billing'){
    if ($type == 'billing') {

        $submenu = 'add_bill_to_customer';
        $pageTitle = 'Add Bill To Customer';
    } else if ($type == 'shed') {

        $submenu = 'add_pickup_drop_customer';
        $pageTitle = 'Add Pickup Drop Customer';
    } else if ($type == 'shipper') {
        $submenu = 'add_shipper_customer';
        $pageTitle = 'Add Shipper Customer';
    } else {
        $submenu = '';
        $pageTitle = 'Add Customer'; 
    }
    $record = json_decode('{"id":null,"name":"", "name_2":"","company":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","contact":"","contact_ext":"","fax":"","email":"","contact_2":"","contact_ext_2":"","sales":"","notes":"","type":"2","invoicing_method":"2", "payment_plan_days":"3", "is_active":"0","lane_lists":"","is_deleted":"0","approved":"0","approved_date":null,"comment":null,"unserialized_lanes":[],"since":"","unserialized_comment":[]}');
    $this->data=array('page_title'=>$pageTitle, 'record'=>$record,'main_menu'=>'customers','submenu'=>$submenu);
    layout($this,'customers/add');
}
```

I am getting this error when adding new customer

```
    <div id="container">
    <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
    <p>Error Number: 1054</p><p>Unknown column 'contact_ext_2' in 'field list'</p><p>INSERT INTO `customers` (`name`, `company`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `contact`, `contact_ext`, `contact_2`, `contact_ext_2`, `email`, `fax`, `notes`, `invoicing_method`, `has_same_address`, `mailing_address`, `mailing_city`, `mailing_state`, `mailing_zip`, `is_active`, `approved`, `approved_date`, `lane_lists`, `created_at`, `created_by`) VALUES ('MAN', 'Helllo Somthing ', '7057 N LA PAZ AVE', 'FRESNO', 'CA', '93722', '1-209-683-9325', '', '1-020-396-3932', '', 'AMAN1381SINGH@GMAIL.COM', '1-023-369-9632', 'HFKLHF FAFJAS ;LFA', '2', '1', '7057 N LA PAZ AVE', 'FRESNO', 'CA', '93722', '0', '0', NULL, 'a:1:{i:0;O:8:\"stdClass\":6:{s:10:\"from_state\";s:2:\"HI\";s:8:\"to_state\";s:2:\"CT\";s:10:\"to_state_2\";s:2:\"CO\";s:10:\"to_state_3\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"to_state_4\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"to_state_5\";s:0:\"\";}}', 1541084737, '24')</p><p>Filename: modules/admin/models/Admin_model.php</p><p>Line Number: 79</p>    </div>
```

The edit function is working fine with this

my model function

```
function addCustomer($data){
    $this->db->insert('customers', $data);
    $id= $this->db->insert_id();
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: As error clears contact_ext_2 this column is not in customer table

Comment: its there and my edit function is working fine when I am saving edit data

Comment: best add table customer structure here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error quite simply means that `contact_ext_2` which is in your json decoded array, isn't a column in the database. I assume this is erroneously added somewhere on the front end. You can unset the column via `unset($record['contact_ext_2'])` before pushing your data to the model (which I can't see in your code).

UPDATE:

After looking at your database I see it is a field you want, however you named it incorrectly! it should be `contact_2_ext` and you have `contact_ext_2`. rename it and it should work fine!

Comment: so add unset($record['contact_ext_2']) in my controller ??

Comment: this would be in your controller but you can also add it in your model, just it wouln't be `$record` there it would be `unset($data['contact_ext_2'])`.... i'm assuming this isn't a field in your database correct?

Comment: **^ please disregard this!** after looking at your database I see it is a field you want, however you named it incorrectly! it should be contact_2_ext and you have contact_ext_2. rename it in your js and should work fine!

Comment: I added an image in of my table its shows there is column

Comment: see previous comment in bold

Comment: Thank you for bringing that into notice. Its working now